# Incorrect date being returned from SQL DB with Python script

Tags: python, sql, datetime, pyodbc

I have an SQL DB which I am trying to extract data from. When I extract date/time values my script adds three zeros to the date/time value, like so: `2011-05-03 15:25:26.170000`
Below is my code in question:

```
value_Time = ('SELECT TOP (4) [TimeCol] FROM [database1].[dbo].[table1]')
cursor.execute(value_Time)
for Timerow in cursor:
    print(Timerow)
    Time_list = [elem for elem in Timerow]
```

The desired result is that there is not an additional three zeros at then end of the date/time value so that I can insert it into a different database.

Values within `Time_List` will contain the incorrect date/time values, as well as the `Timerow` value.

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the datatype of `TimeCol` column?

Comment: datetime @SalmanA

Comment: A friendly advice: It's much easier to read sql queries into `pandas dataframe` with `pd.read_sql()`, and manipulate the data in `pandas`

Comment: By "an SQL DB" do you mean a Microsoft SQL Server database? Also, what is the "different database" into which you will be inserting the values? Please [edit] / tag your question as appropriate.

Comment: Also, please show and not tell us: *Values within Time_List will contain the incorrect date/time values, as well as the Timerow value.*

Comment: They are incorrect like so `2011-05-03 15:25:26.170000` three additional zeros

Comment: What is the original SQL Server date time? Without the additional zeroes?

Comment: 2011-05-03 15:25:26.170

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
value_Time = ('SELECT TOP (4) [TimeCol] FROM [database1].[dbo].[table1]')
cursor.execute(value_Time)
row=cursor.fetchone()
for i in range(len(row)):
    var=datetime.strftime(row[i], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print(var)
```

Comment: This results in the following error: `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime` on the 7th line of code in your example @Vijay

Comment: Now it's should work.It was strftime i wrongly wrote strptime.I rewrote my code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a wrapper to surround your date control example "yyyy/mm/dd/hh/mm/ss" or "yyyymmddhhmmss"

Format((Datecontrol),"yyyy/mm/dd/hh/mm/ss")